# Enviar contexto a una plantilla padre en django

Tags: html, python, django, herencia

Necesito enviar el contexto a una plantilla que esta siendo heredada en un proyecto de django

En el views.py cargo la informacion dentro del contexto para que la envia a las plantillas html:

```
Principal(request):
   nombres = {'usuario_1':'juan', 'usuario_2':'andres'}
   contexto = nombres
   return render(request, "Principal.html", contexto)
```

Tengo 2 html, uno es el que se muestra y al que se hace referencia dentro de views.py, y el otro es un html que tiene la base del primer html, es decir, un html padre y uno hijo.

Principal.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<p id="Mensaje de bienvenida">Hola mundo</p>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html:

```
<html>
...
<body>
   <select>
      <option>{{usuario_1}}</option>
      <option>{{usuario_2}}</option>
   </select>
   {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
...
</html>
```

Desde views, se le envia informacion a el html Principal, por esta razon, las variables que llamo desde base.html no se cargan, es esto lo que deseo arreglar

Comment: Debe haber un error en la comunidad, ya dos preguntas sin ninguna intervención, ni en respuestas ni en comentarios

Comment: Si nadie te responde, puede ser que sea que nadie encontró la manera de poderte ayudar. Yo por ejemplo no se nada de Django, solo comentaba para que no te sientas ignorado. Puedes intentar llegar a más gente ofreciendo una recompensa o preguntar en el sitio en ingles que quizá allí haya más gente que vea tu pregunta.

Comment: Puedes leer [¿Qué debo hacer si nadie contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo la misma pregunta, se puede realizar por medio de una vista TemplateView, pero igual yo requiero hacerlo con una funciòn, asi como tu codigo, si alguien nos puede ayudar.

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/333742)

Answer (score 0):

El modelo usado por Django, contiene una forma de herencia que puedes verla como en un lenguaje de programacion normal, pero en este caso en herencia de plantillas.

En cualquier lenguaje para que un objeto hijo se encargue de un comportamiento que cree que su padre no maneja bien, debe sobrescribir dicho comportamiento.

Para indicar que un comportamiento puede ser sobrescrito por sus descendientes muchos lenguajes usan palabras reservadas, como C# usa `virtual`

En el caso de Django, la plantilla padre debe dejar un `{% block ... %}...{% endblock %}`, introduciendo el comportamiento que quiere por defecto dentro de esta definicion de bloque.

Esto lo que provoca es que si ninguna plantilla hijo sobrescribe el bloque, este se queda como en su definicion padre.

En caso que la plantilla hijo o descendiente la sobrescriba, se sustituye el contenido de la definicion original del bloque, radicada en la plantilla padre.

---

Lo que quise decir con esto anterior es que no se muestran las variables porque Django no esta recargando la plantilla padre, la cual previamente se les inyectaron las variables que iba a mostrar, por eso Django no vuelve a tocar dicha plantilla... En solucion a esto puede usar el metodo que comentaba anteriormente, para que el diccionario con `usuario_1` y `usuario_2` puedan ser usados por la plantilla padre, o sea, `base.html`, debe dejar la seccion marcada con las etiquetas `select`, dentro de un `{% block ... %}`, y que `Principal.html` sobrescriba este bloque

Espero le ayude

Comment: Buena explicación, pero no responde a la pregunta:(  . El pregunta porque las variables no se muestran dentro de la plantilla cuando se carga la pagina(O eso es lo que entiendo), no que son las plantillas.

Comment: Lo que quise decir con mi respuesta es que no se muestran las variables porque Django no esta recargando la plantilla padre, la cual previamente se les inyectaron las variables que iba a mostrar, por eso Django no vuelve a tocar dicha plantilla... En solucion a esto puede usar el metodo que comentaba anteriormente, para que el diccionario con `usuario_1` y `usuario_2` puedan ser usados por la plantilla padre, o sea, `base.html`, debe dejar la seccion marcada con las etiquetas `select`, dentro de un `{% block ... %}`, y que `Principal.html` sobrescriba este bloque

Comment: por favor digame si me me hice explicar y si debo añadir esta aclaracion a mi respuesta @DanielBriceño

Comment: Si, ¿porque no añadir esta explicación a la respuesta?. Gracias por la explicación.